# Implications of compactness in $A\subseteq B\subseteq E$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(E,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq B\subseteq E$. Consider the following claims

1. $A$ is compact in $E$
2. $A$ is compact in $B$
3. $B$ is compact in $E$

Since $\left.\left.\tau\right|_B\right|_A=\left.\tau\right|_A$ it should hold (1.) $\Rightarrow$ (2.). On the other hand, if $A$ is closed and $E$ is Hausdorff, it should hold (3.) $\Rightarrow$ (1.). Are the any other implications which are true?

*Remark*: And just to be sure: The terminology (1.) does mean nothing else than $(A,\left.\tau\right|_A$) is compact and (2.) does mean that $(A,\left.\left.\tau\right|_B\right|_A)$ is compact, right?

Comment: I don't see why is it that you wrote that “if $A$ is closed and $E$ is Hausdorff, it should hold (3.) $\implies$ (1.)”. You are neither assuming that $A$ is closed nor that $E$ is Hausdorff, right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That's why I wrote that this implication holds **if** $A$ is closed and $E$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

$(1)\implies (2)$.

$(2)\not\implies (3)$.
Let $E=\Bbb{R}$, $B=(0,1)$ and take $A$ any finite subset of $B$.

$(3)\not\implies (1)$.
Let $E=\Bbb{R}$, $B=[0,2]$ and $A=(0,1)$.

$(1)\not\implies (3)$.

Comment: $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ also holds; compactness is "absolute".